# Jquery Datatables: Search API is very slow in Firefox but fast in chrome, IE, safari

Tags: jquery, firefox, datatables

I'm using datatables with 50000 rows. When I try to filter result, the speed on Firefox is very slow but still fast on other browser. Here is sample of my code:

```
$('#search').on('keyup change', function() {
    $('#myTable').api().search($(this).val()).draw();
});

$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aaData" : aaData,
    "bAutoWidth" : false,
    "bSort" : false,
    "deferRender" : true,
    "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
    "sDom" : '<"top"lif<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ipl<"clear">>',
    "aoColumns" : myColumnsDef
});
```

I'm using datatables v1.10.10 and Firefox v42

Comment: I would post this in the datatables.net forum. Sounds like you've found a bug in datatables.

Comment: I've post this in datatables forum too. But I think it's hard if I don't have some example. Where can I simulate the datatables with 50000 rows of data?

Comment: Have you considered server-side processing?

Comment: I think I will not doing server-side because some business issue. Have you ever met this situation before?

Comment: I can't say that I have had this specific issue, but I've found that for large numbers of rows Server Side processing is usually the way to go.